# Https client ktor and kotlin multiplatform

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, ktor

according to the documentation ktor to use HTTPS connection between client and server you need to use this code:

```kotlin
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.security.KeyStore
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager

object SslSettings  {
    fun getKeyStore(): KeyStore {
        val keyStoreFile = FileInputStream("keystore.jks")
        val keyStorePassword = "foobar".toCharArray()
        val keyStore: KeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType())
        keyStore.load(keyStoreFile, keyStorePassword)
        return keyStore
    }

    fun getTrustManagerFactory(): TrustManagerFactory? {
        val trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm())
        trustManagerFactory.init(getKeyStore())
        return trustManagerFactory
    }

    fun getSslContext(): SSLContext? {
        val sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")
        sslContext.init(null, getTrustManagerFactory()?.trustManagers, null)
        return sslContext
    }

    fun getTrustManager(): X509TrustManager {
        return getTrustManagerFactory()?.trustManagers?.first { it is X509TrustManager } as X509TrustManager
    }
}
```

In Kotlin multiplatform , to create a HTTPS server you need to use the configuration file application.conf:

```
ktor {
    deployment {

        sslPort = 8888
    }
    application {
        modules = [ org.example.project.ApplicationKt.module ]
    }

    security {
        ssl {
            keyStore = src/main/resources/keystore.jks
            keyAlias = server
            keyStorePassword = foobar
            privateKeyPassword = foobar
        }
    }
}
```

and Application.kt with server code:

```kotlin
package org.example.project

import io.ktor.server.application.*
import io.ktor.server.request.*
import io.ktor.server.response.*
import io.ktor.server.routing.*
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("NettyLogger")

fun main (args: Array<String>) : Unit = io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain.main(args)

fun Application.module() {
    try {
        routing {
            get("/") {
                call.respondText(" Ktor: base link ")
                logger.info("responding to /")
            }
        }
    }catch (e : Exception){
        logger.info("exception in Application.module() = " + e.printStackTrace())
    }
}
```

SslSettings in Kotlin multiplatform can only be used as jvm code, but how to create an https connection between server and client on Desktop and Android?

I tried calling the code through the common code module, but then separate code is created for each platform.

This is what the general code for connecting via HTTPS looks like:

```kotlin
import SERVER_IP
// error
//import SslSettingsCommon
import io.ktor.client.*
import io.ktor.client.engine.cio.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking

//error
//private val sslSettingsCommon : SslSettingsCommon = SslSettings()
class HttpsApiClient {

    val ip = SERVER_IP
    fun connect (){
        runBlocking {
            val client = HttpClient(CIO) {
                engine {
                    https {
                        serverName = ip
//                        error
//                        trustManager = SslSettings.getTrustManager()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

errors occur due to missing dependencies for the desktop platform

Comment: So are you trying to configure SSL for the client or the server? What problem are you trying to solve?